# Ignore first line in FINDSTR search

Tags: powershell, findstr, powershell-cmdlet

I am searching an object-oriented Modelica library for a certain string using the following command in the Windows 7 PowerShell:

```
findstr /s /m /i "Searchstring.*" *.*
```

[click for findstr documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx)

The library consists of several folders containing text files with the actual code in them. To reduce the number of (unwanted) results, I have to ignore the first line of every text file.

Unfortunately, I cannot work out how to do this with the `findstr` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Select-String` instead of `findstr`

To get all matches excluding the ones on the first line try something like this:

```
Select-String -Path C:\dir\*.* -pattern "Searchstring*" | where {$_.LineNumber -gt 1}
```

If you have to search subdirectories you can pair it with `Get-Childitem`:

```
Get-Childitem C:\dir\*.* -recurse | Select-String -pattern "Searchstring*" | where {$_.LineNumber -gt 1}
```

Comment: I used the following code to search all files and subdirectories: `Get-ChildItem .\* -recurse | Select-String -pattern "Searchstring" | where {$_.LineNumber -gt 1}`. Your help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using `findstr` you could simply pipe the output into `Select-Object`:

```
findstr /s /m /i "Searchstring.*" *.* | select -Skip 1
```